# Can i pass a variable from a file included to the page that included that file?

Tags: jsp

i have a page called index.jsp that includes another page called include.jsp

this is index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<jsp:include page=include.jsp" >    
</body>
</html>
```

include.jsp

```
String var="hello";
```

How can i use in index.jsp, the variable var declared in include.jsp?
Thank u

Answer (score 1):

The two pages will have different PageContext and hence the variable declared in one JSP is not accessible directly in another JSP. What you can do is to add the variable that you declared in include.jsp to a request attribute and then use the same in index.jsp.